# Is there a scrollviewer WP7 control which have categories title, which categories title stick on top of control when scrolling?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a scrollviewer WP7 control which have categories title? The category title can stick on the top of the control when the content of this category scrolling in the view. Which can let user know current category of current scrolling content if the scrolling content is long. If current category content is scrolling up out of screen, the title of category will scrolling up with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are refering to the "LongListSelector".

You can download this control from [Windows Phone SilverLight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034)

Then follow one of the tutorials online. They are a bit lengthy for me to describe in detail here, so I'd recommend looking at working through one of these links (or google your own):

[Windows Phone LongListSelector In depth](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api)

[Windows Phone LongListSelector Walkthrough](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/LongListSelector-walkthrough)

Comment: Thank you. I saw the LongListSelector control samples and demos. It can make switching to other categories easier with show all categories list when tapping it. 
The control I'd like to find is that the category title will always stay on top of the control when the items of this category is scrolling in screen, it can help user know what is current category even them scroll to very bottom of this category, when all items of the category scrolling up, the category title will scroll up with the last items. Is there such kind of category list control?

Comment: i think for that you will have to set the ListHeaderTemplate to whichever group is being viewed, as that remains static when scrolling through the list

Comment: Thank you. Setting list header will works for this requirement. But it wasn't accepted by UI designer :) It looks I have to implement a customer control. :)